# What would be the onomatopoeia for "spit"?

Tags: pronunciation, onomatopoeia

Just wanted to know how to write in a chat room the sound for "spit".

As in "meow" for the sound that a cat makes, what would you write for the sound of the verb "spit"?

(Google wasn't very helpful, so turning to some native speakers for some help)

Comment: "Ach-tooey!" is my favorite!

Comment: Isn't that the one for "sneeze"? (confused) ;-)

Comment: Perhaps something like "Pfff!"

Comment: @Fabby - I know the sneeze as "achoo!".  "Ach" is the snort part and "tooey" is the projecting-the-snot-out-of-the-mouth part.

Comment: I thought _spit_ was pretty onomatopoeic already, with the _s_ being the inhaling and the _pit_ at the point of ejection.

Comment: @KristinaLopez: Cool!  Now I know ever more!

Comment: @Frank: I think you're just too well-brought up! ;-)

Comment: "Spit" is itself almost onomatopoeic.

Comment: @DavidGarner I've always interpreted/used "pfff" to be the sound made when pronouncing the word "pfff"--that is, blowing air through pursed lips. Spitting is not involved. I use it to express sarcasm/disdain/humor/etc., as in "Pfff, whatever."

Comment: Yes, Kyle, I think you're right.  It was a feeble attempt.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

> [**ptui!**](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=DpPw5oNvKyQC&pg=PA197&dq=%22ptui%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=FTraVKG7BsncaqvGgqAG&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=%22ptui%22&f=false) *- expresses **disgust**; usually accompanied by **spitting***

For example...

> [...she coughed and corralled the rattle in her chest into her mouth then **ptui!** - spat on the ground](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=AcS9Rac3PMIC&pg=PA154&lpg=PA154&dq=ptui%20spat&source=bl&ots=rsQBfC665y&sig=cIC4xGi401EMlM9PrnnJiO6PML8&hl=en&sa=X&ei=oDnaVIK6GsHPaJnSgbgG&ved=0CCwQ6AEwAg#v=onepage&q=ptui%20spat&f=false)

There aren't many examples of the *verb* form (as with the cat *meowed*, the dog *woofed*), but I did manage to find this one...

> [Spit should be blown, not **ptuied** weakly with the lips, which often results in dribble.](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=4VvVjZRynLMC&q=%22ptuied%22&dq=%22ptuied%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=0zraVIKPOM6qaYzzgpAL&redir_esc=y)

---

OED (subscription-only) don't list the spelling **ptooey** , but they do have this in their entry for...

> **ptui**
>    Chiefly N. Amer.
>    Etymology:  Imitative. Compare **pfui** int., **phooey** int., and also **ptish** int., **pshaw** int., etc.

Comment: We must have posted right around the same time. Interestingly, the NGram shows *ptui* as more prevalent overall in both the US and GB corpora (so +1 for that), but I exclusively recall the *ptooey* spelling from children's books, likewise *phooey* not *pfui*.

Comment: @choster: I did the same research as you and came to the same conclusion: ptooey gets 37K google hits and ptui 288K hits, so I hope you don't mind just getting a bunch of rep from this, but let the kudos go to FumbleFingers...  ;-)

Comment: @Fabby: I don't think there's any doubt *ptui* and *ptooey* are just spelling variants - of which I'm sure the former is more common in BrE, but maybe not so much in AmE. But to me *ptooey* is reminiscent of *phooey* (which I find *very* "folksy American"), so I'm with OED on this one (rather than Collins, who don't list *ptui*). Both dictionaries have *phooey*, obviously (*orig. U.S.*, according to OED).

Comment: Charlie Brown cartoons were very fond of "ptui!".

Comment: I had never seen that spelling before. Crazy!

Comment: I always used the spelling "Ptooie"!

Comment: @Zibbobz: Given that *He spat the words out* invariably implies *(inter alia)* that he spoke in a rapid/clipped style (rather than *drawling*, for example), it seems more appropriate to me that we should reflect this with the shorter spelling. All these "double-O" versions seem somewhat *gooey/cooey* to me (a load of *hooey*, in fact! :)

Comment: @FumbleFingers Given that this is spit we're talking about, a bit of 'gooeyness' makes sense.

Comment: I wonder what the present participle of _ptui_ might be. _Ptuiing_ (only word I can think of in the English language that contains the sequence _-uii-_)? _Ptuieing_? _Ptuying_? Or just generally wet?

Comment: @Janus: Gimmie a break! At least I managed to find a ***past** participle* usage based on this spelling. You try doing that for ***ptooey**!* (*ptooeyed?, ptooeied?* - I'm not sure any sane writer would even *attempt* that one! :)

Answer (score 36):

The most common word is probably

> **[ptooey](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/ptooey)**: an imitation of the sound of spitting [Collins]

It is also spelled *[ptui](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/american/ptui)*. In fact, this spelling is more common in both the British and American English Google Books corpora according to the NGram, but for whatever reason I'm finding the *ptooey* spelling easier to find in published media, from *[CSM](http://www.csmonitor.com/Science/2014/0904/Ptooey!-Sharpshooter-fish-hunts-by-spitting-say-researchers.)* to *[The New Yorker](http://www.newyorker.com/magazine/2008/09/22/ptooey)*. Both spellings are [playable in Scrabble](http://www.merriam-webster.com/scrabble/finder/ptooey).

Comment: TIL! I have known this word since I was a kid, but never had any idea it was referring to spitting.  It sounds more like "phooey" so I guess I just assumed it had a similar meaning.

Comment: Choster: Just don't think I'm stingy: the first upvotes both you and FumbleFingers got were mine!  ;-)  And thanks again for the research and entertainment!

Comment: Yes Scrabble acceptance is important!

Answer (score 26):

As indicated in the comments, "Spit" is actually onomatopoetic. It comes from the Old English word "Spittan", which was the imitation of the sound of spitting.

Comment: An upvote as that's *exactly* what I thought too, before choster and FumbleFingers came up with their version (And both those words sound really alike, *and* sound like the Onomatopoeia in my native language, so I'll be going with one of them a bit later...)

Comment: In fact, the origin is much more ancient. It appears in PIE (proto-indo-european). No doubt every culture that has ever existed has had something like this, as it is imitative in nature. Latin had spuo, Greek had ptuo, etc. Another upvote from me for the same reason.

Comment: I agree with you that "spit" is an onomatopoeic word, but so is "dog" and nowadays it just "barks"...  **;-)**

Comment: @Fabby _Dog_ is onomatopoeic? How so? Its origins are entirely unknown so etymology is of no help, but it doesn't sound particularly onomatopoeic to me…

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet:  If you have a dog, just do the following experiment yourself: call it over, look it in the eyes and go "Dog", "Dog!", "Dog-dog-dog!", "Doooog!" and listen to its response...  ;-)  Dog, Hund, Hond, 
Собака are all onomatopoeic.

Answer (score 4):

A common phrase that has been seen in some older southern movies would be...

"Hawk a spitooey"

Not that spitooey is acceptable to use but it leads into the suggestion that "ptooey" would be the correct onomatopoeia.

Comment: Good to remind me of the word "hawk"...  Haven't heard that since I watched some spaghetti-westerns as a kid... (worthy of an upvote!)

Comment: It's "hock", not "hawk". Though "hock" is generally only used in the specific phrase "hock a loogie". (Interestingly, "loogie" is also only generally used in that same phrase.)

Comment: Hm, is "spitooey" possibly a play on "spitoon"?

Comment: or "hock a loogie"